# CakePHP find related model data

Tags: cakephp, model, find, associations

I got classes User and Firm:

```
class Firm extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Firm';
    var $belongsTo = 'User';
}
```

and:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany ='Post';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Firm';
}
```

everything works fine, but how do I search Firm if user id = for example, 5?
I used:

```
$this->set('firms',$this->Firm->User->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>'5'))));
```

and on my view i put:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firma</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($firms as $firm): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $firm ['Firm']['firm_id']; ?></td>  //line 9
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

But when I enter my view I get the error:

`"Notice (8): Undefined index: firm_id [APP\views\firms\wylistuj.ctp, line 9]"`

Comment: Could you show the output of <pre> <?php print_r($firms); ?> </pre> in your view?

Answer (score 0):

'firm_id' would be in your join table, not your Firm model.

If your looking to display the id of the current Firm, you should just need this

```
<td> <?php echo $firm['Firm']['id']; ?> </td>
```

Comment: still doesn't work. It says: Undefined index: id [APP\views\firms\wylistuj.ctp, line 9].

Comment: I got debug SQL command like this:
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, [..] FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 5

SELECT `Firm`.`id`, `Firm`.`login`, `Firm`.`password`, [..], `FirmsUser`.`user_id`, `FirmsUser`.`firm_id` FROM `firms` AS `Firm` JOIN `firms_users` AS `FirmsUser` ON (`FirmsUser`.`user_id` = 5 AND `FirmsUser`.`firm_id` = `Firm`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to search like this:

```
$this->set('firms',$this->Firm->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Firm.user_id'=>'5'))));
```

This should give you your wanted result.

**Edit:**

In case you want to associate your models with a "has and belongs to many" relationship you need to write your 2 models like this:

```
//user.php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Firm';
}

//firm.php
class Firmextends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Firm';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'User';
}
```

To see how you can work with the association please read the manual section for [HABTM (has and belongs to many) relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM).

Comment: still doesn't work: 1054: Unknown column 'Firm.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Do you even HAVE such a column? For this to work you also need a column `user_id` in your table for the firms.

Comment: Then your associations are wrong. See my edit for how to setup "has and belongs to many" associations.

Comment: You could also *try* deleting your `APP/tmp/cache/` files (leave the folders inside intact, but delete the contents). If you made changes to your models cake could still be using the cached ones.

Comment: Correct, but if he's developing he should always use `Configure::write('debug', 2);` within his core.php. This disables model caching and he get's all the possible errors.

Comment: At lest in cake 2.x I believe the convention is to have the names of the tables in a join table in alphabetical order (so you'd want it to be firms_users).  Not sure if it breaks stuff to not have it that way or no.